# If I serialize an object from a generic function where the object has properties not on its interface, what will be on the serialized object?

Tags: c#, serialization

Example:

I have some object A, that implements interface B.  And let's say interface B only has 1 property, but A has 2 properties.

If I pass object A into a generic function (`where T : InterfaceB`), and i serialize object A inside that function...

Will the serialized object have 2 properties, or 1? Is this just dependent on the serializer?

Comment: Have you tried it? And yes, it depends on the serializer. Show us some code that your question is about and we can tell you (probably).

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you want to serialize obj A, the serializer will just serialize that object and it will not check the interface, but deserializing, the behavior can be different.

for example, If you have to deserialize a JSON stream into a concrete class that has interface properties, you can include the concrete classes as parameters to a constructor for the class! The NewtonSoft deserializer is smart enough to figure out that it needs to use those concrete classes to deserialize the properties.

I hope it will help you to solve your problem.